# Joomla template (white stripe on right side)

Tags: html, css, joomla

www.thames.ikas.sk
if you resize your browser to be half width of your screen... why do I have white stripe on right? why my html and body do not have full width?
there is no problem when when the browser is full width.
There is problem on tablet or phone too.
Please help

Comment: Please consider updating your question to include the relevant HTML, CSS and Javascript snippets here rather than simply pasting a link. For details, please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: imo: as just for cms systems: it's easier just to have a link to the site with the error, then having 10 css files posted here. (reproducing an error that shows up in a cms can be hard, because it can sometimes "work out" when its just html, js and css without the cms behind) There should be an option to "add" code examples to the OP after the solution was found, so everyone with a similar problem can make use of it and it should be accepted to ask cms related problems w/o snippets, of course if someone can provide it, it should be done so ;)

Comment: @Django, if you read through the answers at the link I posted, you will see that one of the big reasons for the rule is that the process of isolating the snippets will often reveal the problem and solution. I won't dispute that the process is _hard_ but it is definitely _useful_.

Comment: yes i agree a 100% with you on the point of "isolating" it out, but why ask anybody if you can find it out by yourself after a certain period of time? i see it in some cases that it wont help to search for the error, because not everbody is a webninja-pro. i'm 100% sure he can fix this problem after he read my answere and the links i gave him. just my snippet wont do it all... so you see its still more a kind of "he asked for where to look regarding the problem" then a "hey there's some code i cant see the error thing", because there is no error per se in his case. its just a little sloppy ^^

Answer (score 0):

You made your design to require a screen of at least 960px wide. Beneath this width some elements are still forced to use this space even though the viewport is smaller than 960px wide.

Try to change your design to not use this forced width, or worse (in my opinion) make sure the background is also stretching to the sides.

Comment: how to force background to stretch to the sides? Did you mean background-size:cover ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#header_inner, #main_body_inner, #navigation_inner, #footer_inner {
width: 960px;
}
```

thats your problem ;)

you should add some [CSS/Media Queries](http://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries) to your template.css e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 960px)
#header_inner, #main_body_inner, #navigation_inner, #footer_inner {
width: 100%;
}
```

and this should go into your index.php of your template to setup the [viewport](http://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://html5-mobile.de/blog/meta-viewport-fuer-mobile-anpassen&act=url) conditions:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

please read both links, i hope that google translate link is working ;)

EDIT: anything that has a fixed width 320px and greater should be adressed with a @media-query, just to make it work with mobile/tablet devices if you want to have your page in a "responsive styling".

check your .logo class (width: 634px)

usually you end up with:

```
/* Default wide-screen styles */

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
/* styles for narrow desktop browsers and iPad landscape */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
/* styles for narrower desktop browsers and iPad portrait */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
/* styles for iPhone/Android landscape (and really narrow browser windows) */
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
/* styles for iPhone/Android portrait */
}

@media (max-width: 240px) {
/* styles for smaller devices */
}
```

Comment: and if you remove the nivo slider almost everthing works as intended